# How to hide irrelevant NULL values in Prompts in OBIEE 11g

Tags: obiee

We have a column that has NULL Record entry, so we cant opt for unchecking NULLABLE field in RPD. Scenario is, we are selecting a particular department ID in prompt and for which the column has a value (Say India) but still shows NULL in the prompt. When we take the Prompt Query fired by OBIEE and run it in SQL, it retrieves only India and NULL doesnt come into picture. Is there any other option to Remove the NULL value in prompt in OBIEE? Any reason why OBIEE shows NULL values?

Answer (score 0):

See this previous post for some guidance. Not all the options will work for you since your situation is different, but it could act as a good starting point.

[How to Remove Null Values from prompts in OBIEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334021/how-to-remove-null-values-from-prompts-in-obiee)

To summarize that link, if you have a limited number of possible values, you could chose specific column Values under Options in the edit prompt dialog box.

Also, checking the box to require user input will sometimes resolve this null value problem, however this is not always the case nor is it always possible depending on your situation.

Finally, try to go to Edit Dashboard Prompt, in Choice List Values drop-down list select SQL Results, then write the SQL statements as column name is not equals to “Unspecfied” (In this way we can remove Null’s also).

Once again, that link is for another question so not all these options are applicable here, but I have found it to be a good starting point.

Comment: No. That will not suit my case. We have about 20 Prompts and we cant have mandatory prompts. Any other solution?

Comment: Is the null value record entry in your database valid? Also, in that previous answer, you cant use SQL to filter out the null option? I know Oracle's recommended action here is to uncheck Nullable in the RPD which you cant seem to do in your case.

Comment: When you post a link as an answer, you should include the core points here in case it goes dead.  Link only answers are prime targets for deletion.

Comment: @BradKoch Thanks. I have edited the link to include the main points. The prime reason for the link was to show the OP that almost an exact duplicate of his question existed with an applicable answer (although not marked as answer, so perhaps more of an applicable comment for now), however adding details in case of a broken link makes sense.